# Using a global vuejs variable in a dynamic href bind

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have an vuejs app in html to upload files through an API (see html). Now, I want to use the data object `name` of the uploaded file (`this.name = file.name`) in a html `href` element a couple of seconds after the file is uploaded. I tried to appear these elements after a couple of seconds, but yielded no valid link:

```
<a :href="`https://***.s3.amazonaws.com/${name}.pdf`">Download</a>
```

and

```
<a :href="`https://***.s3.amazonaws.com/${data.name}.pdf`">Download</a>
```

How to get the name of the file in the download link?

```js
  const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1000000

  /* ENTER YOUR ENDPOINT HERE */
  const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://**********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/uploads'

  new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
          file: '',
          uploadURL: '',
          name: ''
      },
      methods: {
          onFileChange (e) {
              let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files
              if (!files.length) return
              this.createFile(files[0])
          },
          createFile (file) {
              let reader = new FileReader()
              this.name = file.name
              console.log(this.name)
              reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
              reader.onload = (e) => {
                  if (e.target.result.length > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                      return alert('File is loo large.')
                  }
                  this.file = e.target.result
              }
          },
          removeFile: function (e) {
              console.log('Remove clicked')
              this.file = ''
          },
          uploadFile: async function (e) {
              console.log('Upload clicked', this.name)
              // Get the presigned URL
              const response = await axios({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: API_ENDPOINT+'?filename='+this.name
              })
              console.log('Response: ', response)
              let blobData = new Blob([this.file], {type: 'text/csv'})
              console.log('Uploading to: ', response.uploadURL)
              const result = await fetch(response.uploadURL, {
                  method: 'PUT',
                  body: blobData
              })
              console.log('Result: ', result)
              // Final URL for the user doesn't need the query string params
              this.uploadURL = response.uploadURL.split('?')[0]
          },
      }
  })
```

```html
        <div id="app">
          <div v-if="!file">
              <h4>Select a file</h4>
              <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
          </div>
          <div v-else>
              <div>File loaded </div>
              <button v-if="!uploadURL" @click="removeFile">Remove file</button>
              <button v-if="!uploadURL" @click="uploadFile">Upload file</button>
          </div>
          <h2 v-if="uploadURL">Success! File uploaded to bucket.</h2>

          <a :href="`https://bias-scan.s3.amazonaws.com/${name}.pdf`">Download bias scan report</a>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Fixed by `let str = file.name`, remove the suffix with`this.str_name = str.substring(0, str.length - 4)` en logging the console for sake of clarity `console.log(this.str_name)`.